# Is there anyway to define an undefined object in Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Lets say I have a controller in AngularJS:

```
myApp.controller('SearchController',
    function ($scope, UserService) {

        // for intellisense, UserService is undefined here
        var user = UserService.getUsers().then(function(data){
                             // yada yada
                   }, function(err){
                             // yada yada
                   });
    });
```

However, in my intellisense file, I can dynamically inject UserService to get its functions like this:

```
intellisense.addEventListener('statementcompletion', function (event) {
    // tried doing this, but doesn't work!
    // event.target   = {};

    var injector   = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);
    var dependency = injector.get(event.targetName);

    event.items    = [];
    for (method in dependency) {
        intellisense.logMessage(method);
        event.items.push({ name: method, kind: 'field', value: function () { } });
    }

});
```

Now, if I have a global variable (or function variable) defined as `UserService = {}` and inside my controller function I type `UserService.` I will get a pop up of all the functions in the service. But if I don't have it defined, since it is interpreted as `undefined` by intellisense, it can't show me the options even though `statementcompletion` is working (as seen in the Javascript Language Service console).

My question is, apart from annotating the function, is there anyway to define `UserService` as an object in the intellisense file? Defining `event.target = {}` does not work (see intellisense code above).

Comment: The fallback hack that I'm using at this point is to set my object to an empty value if not already set, then I have a target to work with in intellisense. In the above example I would just include $scope = $scope || {}; at the beginning of my function. It's a hack but does work.

Comment: I thought about doing that but it would mess up with the source code, which is not desirable. What I did instead was to "call" the angular components (like controller, service..etc), which are basically functions with empty objects from intellisense code. Voila, you have all the intellisense you want!

Comment: How exactly do you do that? Is there a code sample you can point me to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way that works is to "call" the component functions (controller, services, etc) from intellisense code with empty objects.

I am sure this can be a lot cleaner but here's what I've done:

https://github.com/diwasbhattarai/angularjs-intellisense

**By John Bledsoe:** https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/

**references.js** - add this file as reference in Tools>Options>TextEditor>Javascript>Intellisense>References

```
    /// <reference path="../source/lib/assetBundle.js" />
    /// <reference path="_moduleDecorator.js" />
    /// <reference path="_componentDecorator.js" />
    /// <reference path="../source/app/appBundle.js" />

    intellisense.addEventListener('statementcompletion', function (event) {
    // for core angular objects
    addComponentToIntellisense('ng');
    // for custom objects in application modules
    for (var moduleIndex in modules) {
        addComponentToIntellisense(modules[moduleIndex]);
    }

    function addComponentToIntellisense(module) {
        var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', module]),
            dependency = $injector.get(event.targetName),
            dep;

        if (typeof dependency === "function") dep = new dependency();
        else dep = dependency;

        for (var method in dep) {
            event.items.push({ name: method, kind: 'field', value: dependency[method] });
        }
    }
});
```

**_moduleDecorator.js** - to keep track of all the modules in your app

```
    //_moduleDecorator
    (function () {
    var originalModule = angular.module;
    // TODO change to array
    modules = {};
    var rep = false;
    var count = 0;
    angular.module = function () {
        for (var k in modules) {
            if (modules[k] === arguments[0]) {
                rep = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!rep) modules[count++] = arguments[0];

        return originalModule.apply(angular, arguments);
    };
})();
```

**_componentDecorator.js** - to "call" component functions with empty object parameter

```
    (function () {
    // pick all the components in all modules and initialize them for intellisense
    for (var moduleIndex in modules) {
        var currentModule = angular.module(modules[moduleIndex]),
            queue = currentModule._invokeQueue,
            // add other components such as value, provider, etc later
            angularComponents = ['controller', 'factory', 'service', 'value'];

        for (var i = 0; i < angularComponents.length; i++) {
            var currentComponent    = angularComponents[i],
                originalComponentFn = currentModule[currentComponent];

            currentModule[currentComponent] = (function (currentModule, queue, originalComponentFn) {
                return function () {
                    originalComponentFn.apply(currentModule, arguments);
                    initializeComponents(queue);
                };
            })(currentModule, queue, originalComponentFn);
        }
    }

    function initializeComponents(queue) {
        var elem = queue.filter(function (element) {
            var componentName = element[2][0].toLowerCase();
            return (componentName.indexOf(componentName) !== -1);
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            var tempComp = elem[i][2][1],
                compFunc;

            // for array notation for DI
            if (typeof tempComp !== "function") {
                compFunc = tempComp[tempComp.length - 1];
            } else {
                compFunc = tempComp;
            }

            // 10 parameter dependencies initialization for now
            compFunc({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: That got me over the top! Thanks so much for posting this. I'm considering packaging up my implementation into an (MIT-licensed) GitHub repository but would like your permission to incorporate some of these bits. I've modified it pretty heavily, performing fuzzier matching when an exact match isn't found, allowing for provider injection, and so forth. I just needed the bit to initialize functions with empty parameters.

Comment: No problem. You can go ahead and package it. Glad it helped you :)

Comment: Oh and could you please post the repo here so I can take a look at it?

Comment: For sure. May be this weekend but maybe later, depending.

Comment: I would be really interested in getting this in to Web Essentials for Angular specific Intellisense. Please let me know if you'd be interested in sharing

Comment: @MadsKvistKristensen getting any better Angular support into Web Essentials would be great!

Comment: @MadsKvistKristensen sure! I would be glad to share.

Comment: https://github.com/jmbledsoe/angularjs-visualstudio-intellisense/ is the project I started. It isn't perfect but it gives intellisense in most of the scenarios I have needed, including Jasmine tests. I believe with a bit of attention it could become production-grade and ready for inclusion in something like Web Essentials.

Comment: Awesome. I also created a repo with basically the same code that I posted above. https://github.com/diwasbhattarai/angularjs-intellisense. Thanks for your effort.